# Starting a new activity when a countdown timer hits 0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

I'm making a simple countdown timer app and I am having trouble getting a new activity to start. on the `onFinish()` method I have it call another method, `resetActivity()` which creates a new `Intent` like so:

```
public void resetActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, reset.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

When my timer hits 0, rather than starting the new activity, it just crashes.

I feel like it has something to do with `View`, but I haven't found anything online that helps in my case. most of the pages I come across use a button to pull up a new activity
the reason I have this new activity is simply to change to a new background with a new message and a reset button to start over. if there is a way to change the background when the timer hits 0, I will not need the second activity.

This is my countdownTimer block:

```
public void start() {
    countdowntimer = new CountDownTimer(timeLeft, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long x) {
            timeLeft = x;
            updateTimer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            resetActivity();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Is your `reset` activity registered in manifest? What does it mean to "change background" (change color?)

Comment: yes i can i see <activity android:name=".reset"></activity> in the manifest.
what i mean by changing background is having a new image be set as the new background.

Comment: Two notes: 1) you should add your crash log. 2) it seems like your question is how to set a different background color etc and not how to start a new activity.

Comment: well its not a new background color, its an image. the reason i have a new activity is so that the user is not only shown a new background, but also has a button to press to essentially reset the entire application. the background image on the main activity shows a full glass of beer, while the background activity shows an empty glass, not sure if that is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to change your hosting activity background would be to add `ImageView` to your activity layout:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Having such setup, you can do `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myAwesomeDrawable)` in your timer's onFinish (and calling timer like this for example `new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000)`). I am not sure about your logic in onTick though.

Instead of setting image to ImageView, you can of course transit to new activity just like you mentioned. Assuming activity is registered in manifest like you said, it will just work.

If the above does not help, your logcat is needed.

Comment: will the ```imageView``` cover any android studio text or button? how do i make sure the image is actually set behind any text or buttons that studio displays?

logcat shows this exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shotclock/com.example.shotclock.reset}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.shotclock:layout/activity_reset: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.shotclock:layout/activity_reset: Error inflating class RelativeLayoutLayout

Comment: There is typo in your layout: RelativeLayoutLayout. Must be RelativeLayout

Comment: For the second part of your clarification, you can use either ConstraintLayout or RelativeLayout (more simple), put ImageView first child of the layout and then pack the rest - they will be displayed on top.